# Convergence to root of $F$ for initial value problem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence

Consider the initial value problem $$du/dt=F(u(t)),\;u(0)=0$$ where $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is $C^1$. Assume that $F(0)<0$ and let $\alpha<0$ be the first root of $F$ to left of $0$ (assume it exists). Then show that $u(t)$ converges to $\alpha$.

Here is what I thought: There exists a maximal interval $(a,b)$ where the solution to IVP exists (by Picard). So we want to show that as $t\to b$ then $u(t)\to \alpha$. If $b<\infty$ then we have $u(t)\to\infty$ as $t\to b$. And $u'(0)<0$ so $u'$ must change sign somewhere. Therefore there exists a first root of $u'$. But clearly the function $u$ goes to infinity in this case. Is the problem wrong? If not can someone help with a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Its not true that $u\to\infty$ as $t\to b$. Nothing in the question prevents the case that $F\le 0$. In this case, $\frac{du}{dt} \le 0$ and therefore $u(t) \le 0$, even if the maximal time of existence is finite

Answer (score 1):

Let $u : (a,b)\to\mathbb R$ be the solution of the IVP
$$
u'=F(u), \quad u(0)=0,
$$
which is defined in a maximal interval.

Since $F(0)<0$ and $\alpha$ is the first negative root of $F$, then Uniqueness of solutions, due to smoothness of $F$ implies that:

**Fact I.** $u$ is strictly decreasing in $I=(a,b)$. In particular, $F\big(u(t)\big)<0$, for all $t\in I$. Otherwise, there would be a $\tau\in I$, for which
$F\big(u(\tau)\big)=0$, in which case $u$ would be the solution of 
$$
u'=F(u), \quad u(\tau)=\xi,
$$ 
where $\xi=u(\tau)$. But the above IVP possesses the unique solution $u(t)\equiv\xi$.

**Fact II.** $u(t)>\alpha$, for all $t\in (a,b)$. Otherwise, $u(\tau)=\alpha$, for some $\tau\in I$ and hence $u$ would be the solution of 
$$
u'=F(u), \quad u(\tau)=\alpha.
$$ 
But the above IVP possesses the unique solution $u(t)\equiv\alpha$.

Hence, if $b<\infty$, then $\lim_{t\to b} u(t)$ exists and $\lim_{t\to b} u(t)\ge \alpha$.

Case I. If $\lim_{t\to b} u(t)=\alpha$, then $u$ extends beyond $b$, as the solution of the IVP
$$
u'=F(u), \quad u(b)=\alpha.
$$
However, the above IVP possesses a unique solution $U(t)\equiv \alpha$, and thus $u$ and $U$ do not not coincide left of $b$.
Contradiction.

Case II. If $\lim_{t\to b} u(t)=\beta\in(\alpha,0)$, then $F(\beta)<0$ and
$u$ extends beyond $b$, as the solution of the IVP
$$
u'=F(u), \quad u(b)=\beta.
$$
which contradicts the maximality of $I$.